# Catch browser close

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, session, browser

I need to know if its possible to catch a user closing the browser window. I have tried using `<body onbeforeunload="run_closeScripts()">` which works fine, but this is triggered on every postback! So its not much use if the user hits the refresh button or goes to another page.

Is there a reliable way to detect if its a full browser close rather than a postback?

```
<body onbeforeunload="run_closeScripts()">

<script type="text/javascript">

    function run_closeScripts() {

        //check if the browser is closing and not a postback
        window.alert("Your checkout will be removed!");
        window.location.replace("Exit.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: No in real it isn't.There might be some events could be catch but not all

Comment: The tags of your question indicate the platform you are using, so they don't need to be repeated in your title.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to use JavaScript and you can [google for that](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=detect%20browser%20close%20javascript&aq=f&oq=detect%20browser%20close%20javascript&aqs=chrome.0.57j0j60l2j0l2.4963&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), however, it is worth noting you CANNOT rely on the JavaScript running. Don't put stuff in you require to happen because you can't rely on it.